# How to create a table with multiple data type like char short int string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Now I have two way to do this as below, but I do not know which is better and is there some better way?

```
CREATE TABLE `params_value1` (  
  `params_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `params_value_int8` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `params_value_int16` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `params_value_int32` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `params_value_string` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`params_id`),  
  UNIQUE KEY `params_id_UNIQUE` (`params_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE `params_value2` (  
  `params_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `params_value` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`params_id`),  
  UNIQUE KEY `params_id_UNIQUE` (`params_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The follow picture is main tab used:

[image]

Comment: How do you intend to _use_ this information? If you have all of them together (_int8, _int16, ...), how do you know which one contains de intended value?

Comment: Yes,this is only parts tab of my project, and I have add the main tab used in my project .

Answer (score 2):

Entity-Attribute-Value is the nightmare you are embarking on.  See the additional tag I added.  See a similar tag in stackoverflow.com; there is a lot more discussion there.

It is traditional to have another column in the Attribute table:  entity_id, attribute, value.  Your question applies to how to store `value`; that is only part of the nightmare.

In the cases of integers, simply make it `BIGINT`; that will hold the various sizes (with a little wasted space), and simplify your code some.

Comment: I just know that this is an EAV problem ,thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Best way to store dynamic parameter key/values are as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this can be done by using following method:

[image]

```
create table param_type
(
paramtype_id int,
paramtype varchar(30),
paramunit varchar(30),
prmary key(paramtype_id)
);

create table param_value
(
param_id int,
paramtype_id int,
paramvalue varchar(30),
parimary key(param_id),
foreign key(paramtype_id) references param_type(paramtype_id)
);
```

There are other multiple ways to implements this, still it depends on your exact requirement. I hope this will help you!!

Comment: Yes my tab mode is like this , thank you very much!